# How to use flutter library in native java android application?

Tags: java, android, c++, flutter, android-studio

I am developing an app that needs this library . Currenty, there is no java version. Is it possible to somehow integrate it with my current project.
https://pub.dev/packages/bls_signatures_ffi flutter version
https://github.com/Chia-Network/bls-signatures c++, javascript and python.
Please, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use c++ library through the Java Native Interface (JNI).

See [Add C and C++ code to your project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C++ library in your Android project with the help of [this link.](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code)

But if you want any flutter implementation in your project then you can use bridging to share information in your project. [Using this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)